# What event is called after pressing a menu shortcut key before the menu item click event is called?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menu

I have a ContextMenuStrip attached to a Chart.

Is there an event that is executed between pressing a shortcut key and the actual call to the ToolStripMenuItem Clicked event?

For examle if I press CTRL+S to save something. The SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click() will get called. But what is called just before?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keydown at least. Depends on platform, technology, etc.